# javascript create custom class with custom events

Tags: javascript

let's say I have javascript class.

```
function myClass(){

    function someProcess(){
        listeners.init();
    }

    var listeners = {
        init: function(){},
        message: function(){}
    }

    return {
        on: function( prop ) {
            if ( listeners.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
                return listeners[ prop ];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and then someone creates object like so and uses my custom event

```
var c = new myClass();
c.on('init', function(){
    console.log('init executed');
});
```

now i want to execute init from my **someProcess()** method(which is in myClass). 
So idea is that register custom events and then trigger them from inside my class.

Comment: Sounds like what you are looking for is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do this

```
function MyClass(){

    //@private
    var isFunction = function(functionToCheck){
        var getType = {};
        return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
    }



    //@private
    var listeners = {
        init: [],
        message: []
    }





    return {
        on: function( evName, callback ) {
            if ( listeners.hasOwnProperty( evName ) && isFunction(callback) ) {
                listeners[evName].push(callback);
            }
        },
        fireEvent: function(evName){
            if ( listeners.hasOwnProperty( evName )) {
                for(var i in listeners[evName]){
                    listeners[evName][i]();
                }
            }
        }
    }



}



var a = new MyClass();
a.on('init', function(a){
    console.log('a_1 inited')
})

a.on('init', function(){
    console.log('a_2 inited')
})



var b = new MyClass();
b.on('init', function(){
    console.log('b_1 inited')
})

a.fireEvent('init');
b.fireEvent('init');
```